# Where clause like syntax in lambda expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, lambda

I searched alot but couldnt find the right resolution for my problem.

What i'm trying is very basic in sql but dont know how to make it work in lambda expression here is what im trying to do:

```
    FilteredInOrderquery = mycontext.Websites.OrderBy(website.currentOrderBy + " " + website.sortOrder).Where(
        x => (website.websiteFilterList.Contains(x.site.ToString()))

            &&
            (website.cityFilterList.Contains(x.city.ToString()))

           ).Select(x => new WebsiteData(
              x.RowID,
              x.pagetype,
              x.site,
              x.creationdate ?? DateTime.Today,
              x.expirationdate ?? DateTime.Today,
              x.domainregistrar,
              x.pin,
              x.area,
              x.city,
             ((x.expirationdate ?? DateTime.Today) - DateTime.Today).Days.ToString() + " days"));
```

websitefilterList and cityFilterlist both can be empty as well as can contain more than one item.

Point is that i should be able to get records even if i pass any of the list  as empty (if list is empty then i should get all records of that column)

and if im passing both list with more than one entry ..records matching with those entries only should appear.

currently this is not happening i get error when any of my list is empty. although if any of list is empty then i must get all the records. this is very common requirement but i couldnt find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Where(x => 
(!website.websiteFilterList.Any() || website.websiteFilterList.Contains(x.site.ToString()))
&&
(!website.cityFilterList.Any() || website.cityFilterList.Contains(x.city.ToString())))
```